# How can i pass a parameter to a method in angular 13

Tags: angular

I need to pass a value to a method in angular from a database, such value contains the file location with the image i want to put in the corresponding component, and i've been trying hard to find out how to do it with no success. Here my code

in the HTML

```
<div class="users-wrapper p-2" class="desplazamiento">
<div *ngIf="viewType == 'grid'" fxLayout="row wrap" >
<div
  *ngFor="
    let user of users
      | PacienteSearchPipe: searchText
      | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 6, currentPage: page }"
  fxFlex="100"
  fxFlex.gt-md="33.3"
  fxFlex.md="50"
  fxFlex.sm="50"
  class="p-2"
  >
  <mat-card fxLayout="row" class="p-0 user-content">
    <div
      fxFlex="35"
      fxLayout="column"
      fxLayoutAlign="center center"
      class="{{user.colorFondoImagen}}"
  >
  <div
  class="user-img" **(ngclass)="capturarFile(user.fotoPaciente)"**>
  **<img [src]="previsualizacion">**
  <div 
     fxLayout="row"
     fxLayoutAlign="center center"
     class="social-icons"
  >
  <a [href]="'https://www.facebook.com/'">
  <svg class="mat-icon mat-icon-sm mx-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path
  d="M17,2V2H17V6H15C14.31,6 14,6.81 14,7.5V10H14L17,10V14H14V22H10V14H7V10H10V6A4,4 0 0,1 
  14,2H17Z"
  />
  </svg>
  </a>

  <a [href]="'https://twitter.com/'">
  <svg class="mat-icon mat-icon-sm mx-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path
    d="M22.46,6C21.69,6.35 20.86,6.58 20,6.69C20.88,6.16 21.56,5.32 21.88,4.31C21.05,4.81 
    20.13,5.16 19.16,5.36C18.37,4.5 17.26,4 16,4C13.65,4 11.73,5.92 11.73,8.29C11.73,8.63 
    11.77,8.96 11.84,9.27C8.28,9.09 5.11,7.38 3,4.79C2.63,5.42 2.42,6.16 2.42,6.94C2.42,8.43 
    3.17,9.75 4.33,10.5C3.62,10.5 2.96,10.3 2.38,10C2.38,10 2.38,10 2.38,10.03C2.38,12.11 
    3.86,13.85 5.82,14.24C5.46,14.34 5.08,14.39 4.69,14.39C4.42,14.39 4.15,14.36 
    3.89,14.31C4.43,16 6,17.26 7.89,17.29C6.43,18.45 4.58,19.13 2.56,19.13C2.22,19.13 
    1.88,19.11 1.54,19.07C3.44,20.29 5.7,21 8.12,21C16,21 20.33,14.46 20.33,8.79C20.33,8.6 
    20.33,8.42 20.32,8.23C21.16,7.63 21.88,6.87 22.46,6Z"
  />
  </svg>
  </a>
  <a [href]="'https://plus.google.com/'">
  <svg class="mat-icon mat-icon-sm mx-1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path
     d="M23,11H21V9H19V11H17V13H19V15H21V13H23M8,11V13.4H12C11.8,14.4 10.8,16.4 
     8,16.4C5.6,16.4 3.7,14.4 3.7,12C3.7,9.6 5.6,7.6 8,7.6C9.4,7.6 10.3,8.2 
     10.8,8.7L12.7,6.9C11.5,5.7 9.9,5 8,5C4.1,5 1,8.1 1,12C1,15.9 4.1,19 8,19C12,19 14.7,16.2 
     14.7,12.2C14.7,11.7 14.7,11.4 14.6,11H8Z"
  />
  </svg>
  </a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div fxFlex="65" class="user-details" >
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <h4 class="user-name px-2">
  {{ user.nombres }} {{ user.apellidos }}
  </h4>
  </div>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <div class="info-list mx-2">
  <p fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  <mat-icon class="secondary-text-color">card_membership</mat-icon>
  <span>{{ user.direccion }}</span>
  </p>
  <p fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  <mat-icon class="secondary-text-color">mail_outline</mat-icon>
  <span>{{ user.email }}</span>
  </p>
  <p fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  <mat-icon class="secondary-text-color">call</mat-icon>
  <span>{{ user.telefono }}</span>
  </p>
  <p fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  <mat-icon class="secondary-text-color">location_on</mat-icon>
  <span>{{ user.direccion }}</span>
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  </mat-card>
  </div>
  </div>
```

in the typescript

```
  //this method catches the value of the image file coming from the HTLM
  **capturarFile(event):any** {
  const archivoCapturado = event.target.files[0]
  this.extraerBase64(archivoCapturado).then((imagen: any) => {
  //the variable previsualizacion will send the string converted into base64 to the <img [src] 
  // in the HTML
  **this.previsualizacion = imagen.base**;
  console.log(imagen);
  })
  }

  //this method converts the file into base64 string
  extraerBase64 = async ($event: any) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  try {
      const unsafeImg = window.URL.createObjectURL($event);
      const image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(unsafeImg);
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL($event);
      reader.onload = () => {
      resolve({
      base: reader.result
  });
  };
  reader.onerror = error => {
    resolve({
      base: null
    });
  };

  } catch (e) {
  return null;
  }
  })
```

Maybe this is pretty straigthforward to you because all i need to know is how can i pass the string coming from the database to the method capturarFile().

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Very hard to follow this code, could use some formatting. What is you change ngclass to a click listener? What you think `ngClass` is supposed to do? `(click)="capturarFile(user.fotoPaciente)`

Comment: thank you for answer, yes i need to apply some formatting. in addition, i don't use a click event, because i don't need to click on any button, if you can see i have an *ngFor and the variable user will be gathering the data and at some point will contain the jpg file location and how can i pass this data to the method capturarFile(<<here i need the string>>) which also called the method extraerBase64 which makes the conversion to base64 ?. thanks